# Indicators of horizontal scroll in Android

Tags: android, scroll

I need to make indicators of scrolling to horizontal scroll in Android. 
Indicators sould be round (Sometimes it goes by default in the phone with some standard application).
Typically, these are circles on the number of elements that scroll. Where we are, that is highlighted.

Please, tell me how to do it, or even what to call it.
Thanks.

**Update.**

Sorry, I can't post an image, but here is an [example](http://lh6.ggpht.com/_aW34Jqvch8X96mwf55-yJ-XTNFbPIaBMC_BpZRBnvccAoREFV-xyJRPtssHP1xdBPxCWWgq40Xx6SM). It's GTasks application, which allows to scroll between todo-lists.

Comment: Does some other app have it that you could show us? I'm not sure what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Its called a 'pageview' i think, and there is no standard view component for that in android. Just create a custom view that draws circles to the amount of items you have; make a class that extends View, then override the onDraw() to draw the circles. You probably want some variables that keep the amount of items and the currently shown item number; you can then update that from your horizontal scroll.